# Segmentation Fault in my readFile

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

I am creating a program that will read from a file with the format of what is mentioned below and generate a struct for each line with the corresponding model, engine size, cost, and color. it is segfaulting at what seems to be the line of token = strtok(line, " "); within the while loop and I can't quite figure out why at this point. This does read the file and read the first line, it prints out the first line just fine but seg faults at the point of doing the strtok

```
F150 5.4 26000 white
RAM1500 5.5 30000 orange
F150 5.6 27000 white
RAM1500 5.7 31000 orange
F150 5.8 28000 white
RAM1500 5.9 32000 orange
F150 5.3 29000 white
RAM1500 5.2 33000 orange
```

This is the structure for the array that I am building

```
struct data{

    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};
```

Here is the code for the program that does the reading of the file and generating of the structures

```
         void  readFile(int check){

    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen("hw3.data", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){

        printf("did not find file \n");
        exit(0);
    }


    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            count++;
        }

    }
    if (feof(fp)){

        rewind(fp);

        struct data *vehicles = malloc((sizeof(struct data))* count);


        int index = 0;
        char *token = NULL;

        //Program is seg faulting in this loop along the token = strtok();
        while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){



            token = strtok(line,  " ");




            vehicles[index].model = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);




            strcpy(vehicles[index].model, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[index].engineSize = atof(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[index].cost = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            vehicles[index].color = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[index].color, token);

            free(line);
            line = NULL;
            len = 0;
            index++;


        }

        if(check == 1){

            bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, 0, count);

        }if(check == 2){

            bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, 1, count);

        }if(check == 3){

            bubbleSortInts(vehicles, 0, count);

        }if(check == 4){

            bubbleSortInts(vehicles, 1, count);

        }


        for(int z = 0; z < count; z++){


        free(&vehicles[z].model);
        vehicles[z].model = NULL;
        free(&vehicles[z].color);
        vehicles[z].color = NULL;
        free(&vehicles[z]);


        }

    }
}
```

This is the rest of the code for my program if you want to look at it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data{

    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};


void printStruct(struct data vehicles[], int check){


}


void bubbleSortInts(struct data vehicles[], int check)
{
   int i, j, n;



  // If check == 1 then ascending sort
  if(check == 1){

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].cost > vehicles[j+1].cost){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    // If check == 0 then decending sort
  if(check == 0){

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].engineSize < vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    printStruct(vehicles, n);
    return;          
}

void bubbleSortFloats(struct data vehicles[], int check)
{
   int i, j, n;


  // If check == 1 then ascending sort
  if(check == 1){

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].engineSize > vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    // If check == 0 then decending sort
  if(check == 0){

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].engineSize < vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    printStruct(vehicles, n); 

}
```

main

```
 int main(){

    int check = 1;
    int input, n;

    while (check == 1){

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below\n\n");

        printf("1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low\n");
        printf("2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high\n");
        printf("3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low\n");
        printf("4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n\n");

        printf("Enter a value corresponding to the above menu\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);





        if(input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4 || input == 5){

            if (input == 5){

                exit(0);

            }if (input == 1){

                //sort float high to low
                //bubbleSortFloats(vehicles[], 0);
                readFile(1);

            }if (input == 2){

                //sort float low to high
                //bubbleSortFloats(vehicles[], 1);
                readFile(2);

            }if (input == 3){


                //sort int value high to low
                //bubbleSortInts(vehicles[], 0);
                readFile(3);


            }if (input == 4){

                //sort int value low to high
                //bubbleSortInts(vehicles[], 1);
                readFile(4);

            }

        }else{

            printf("Enter a correct value for the menus above\n\n" );
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing you've used only some of my suggestions, I decided to write a
version that actually works (also you've been working hard for this code).

There is only one thing that its wrong: your `bubbleSortInts` for decending sort
was incorrect, you were comparing `engineSize` and not `cost`, I fixed that.

I've rewritten some parts of the code that handle the menu and the input. Take a
look at how the file is read only once. Once it's in memory, you don't need to
read the file again, so you can read the file first and then enter in the menu
mode. Look at the `free_vehicles` function that shows you how to free the
memory. I use `calloc` to get the memory for the array. `calloc` has the benefit
that it sets the allocated memory to 0. This is great for initializing structs
with pointers that have to be free. You can free the whole thing with
`free_vehicles` even before the whole array is full, for example when `strtok`
returns `NULL`. In the error handling of this case, you can simple do

```
if(token == NULL)
{
    free_vehicles(vehicles, *len);
    return NULL;
}
```

and the `free` will be correct because `free(NULL)` is allowed.
I've omitted the checks of `strtok` and the copy of `model` and `color`,
so you can add this checks.

You can take the following code as it is, I compiled it and tested it (see
output down below). So you can use this code as your code base for later
improvements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct data {
    char *model;
    float engineSize;
    int cost;
    char *color;
};

void print_vehicles(struct data *vehicles, size_t len)
{
    if(vehicles == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        printf("Vehicle %lu: %-10s engine size: %-4f, price: %-4d USD, color: %s\n",
                i+1, vehicles[i].model, vehicles[i].engineSize, vehicles[i].cost,
                vehicles[i].color);
    }
    puts("");
}

struct data *readFile(size_t *len)
{
    if(len == NULL)
        return NULL;

    struct data *vehicles = NULL;
    *len = 0;

    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen("hw3.data", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){

        fprintf(stderr, "could not open file\n");
        return NULL;
    }


    // finding out the number of lines
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n')
            (*len)++;
    }

    if (feof(fp)){

        rewind(fp);

        // allocate memory
        vehicles = calloc(*len, sizeof *vehicles);

        int index = 0;
        char *token = NULL;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t line_length = 0;
        const char *delim = " \n"; // getting rid of \n as well

        //Program is seg faulting in this loop along the token = strtok();
        while (getline(&line, &line_length, fp)!= -1){

            token = strtok(line, delim);

            vehicles[index].model = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[index].model, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            vehicles[index].engineSize = atof(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            vehicles[index].cost = atoi(token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            vehicles[index].color = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(vehicles[index].color, token);

            free(line);
            line = NULL;
            line_length = 0;
            index++;
        }

        // freeing the last line
        free(line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return vehicles;
}

void free_vehicles(struct data *vehicles, size_t len)
{
    if(vehicles == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        free(vehicles[i].model);
        free(vehicles[i].color);
    }

    free(vehicles);
}

void bubbleSortInts(struct data *vehicles, size_t len, int check)
{
   int i, j, n = len;



  // If check == 1 then ascending sort
  if(check == 1){

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].cost > vehicles[j+1].cost){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    // If check == 0 then decending sort
  if(check == 0){

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].cost < vehicles[j+1].cost){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    return;          
}


void bubbleSortFloats(struct data *vehicles, size_t len, int check)
{
   int i, j, n = len;


  // If check == 1 then ascending sort
  if(check == 1){

   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].engineSize > vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }
    // If check == 0 then decending sort
  if(check == 0){

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){     

       // Last i elements are already in place   
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){


           if (vehicles[j].engineSize < vehicles[j+1].engineSize){

                struct data temp = vehicles[j+1];
                vehicles[j+1] = vehicles[j];
                vehicles[j] = temp; 

           }
        }
    }
  }

}


int read_menu(void)
{
    int input;
    printf("Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below\n\n");

    printf("1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low\n");
    printf("2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high\n");
    printf("3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low\n");
    printf("4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n\n");

    printf("Enter a value corresponding to the above menu\n");

    char line[1024];
    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
    {
        char *tmp;
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
        input = strtol(line, &tmp, 0);

        if(*tmp == 0)
            return input;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct data *vehicles = NULL;
    size_t num_of_vehicles = 0;

    int input = -1;

    // read data only once
    vehicles = readFile(&num_of_vehicles);

    if(vehicles == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while((input = read_menu()) != 5)
    {
        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, num_of_vehicles, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                bubbleSortFloats(vehicles, num_of_vehicles, 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                bubbleSortInts(vehicles, num_of_vehicles, 0);
                break;
            case 4:
                bubbleSortInts(vehicles, num_of_vehicles, 1);
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }

        print_vehicles(vehicles, num_of_vehicles);
    }

    // free the data
    free_vehicles(vehicles, num_of_vehicles);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
$ valgrind ./car-db
==12625== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12625== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12625== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12625== Command: ./car-db
==12625== 
Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below

1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low
2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high
3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low
4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high
5. Exit

Enter a value corresponding to the above menu
1
Vehicle 1: RAM1500    engine size: 5.900000, price: 32000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 2: F150       engine size: 5.800000, price: 28000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 3: RAM1500    engine size: 5.700000, price: 31000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 4: F150       engine size: 5.600000, price: 27000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 5: RAM1500    engine size: 5.500000, price: 30000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 6: F150       engine size: 5.400000, price: 26000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 7: F150       engine size: 5.300000, price: 29000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 8: RAM1500    engine size: 5.200000, price: 33000 USD, color: orange

Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below

1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low
2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high
3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low
4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high
5. Exit

Enter a value corresponding to the above menu
2
Vehicle 1: RAM1500    engine size: 5.200000, price: 33000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 2: F150       engine size: 5.300000, price: 29000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 3: F150       engine size: 5.400000, price: 26000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 4: RAM1500    engine size: 5.500000, price: 30000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 5: F150       engine size: 5.600000, price: 27000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 6: RAM1500    engine size: 5.700000, price: 31000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 7: F150       engine size: 5.800000, price: 28000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 8: RAM1500    engine size: 5.900000, price: 32000 USD, color: orange

Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below

1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low
2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high
3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low
4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high
5. Exit

Enter a value corresponding to the above menu
3
Vehicle 1: RAM1500    engine size: 5.200000, price: 33000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 2: RAM1500    engine size: 5.900000, price: 32000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 3: RAM1500    engine size: 5.700000, price: 31000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 4: RAM1500    engine size: 5.500000, price: 30000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 5: F150       engine size: 5.300000, price: 29000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 6: F150       engine size: 5.800000, price: 28000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 7: F150       engine size: 5.600000, price: 27000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 8: F150       engine size: 5.400000, price: 26000 USD, color: white

Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below

1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low
2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high
3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low
4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high
5. Exit

Enter a value corresponding to the above menu
4
Vehicle 1: F150       engine size: 5.400000, price: 26000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 2: F150       engine size: 5.600000, price: 27000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 3: F150       engine size: 5.800000, price: 28000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 4: F150       engine size: 5.300000, price: 29000 USD, color: white
Vehicle 5: RAM1500    engine size: 5.500000, price: 30000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 6: RAM1500    engine size: 5.700000, price: 31000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 7: RAM1500    engine size: 5.900000, price: 32000 USD, color: orange
Vehicle 8: RAM1500    engine size: 5.200000, price: 33000 USD, color: orange

Enter a value corresponding to a option on the menu below

1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low
2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high
3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low
4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high
5. Exit

Enter a value corresponding to the above menu
5
==12625== 
==12625== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12625==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12625==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 8,072 bytes allocated
==12625== 
==12625== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12625== 
==12625== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12625== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct data *vehicles = malloc((sizeof(struct data))* count);
int count2 = 0;
..
while (getline(&line, &len, fp)!= -1){
  token = strtok(line,  " ");
  ...
  strcpy(vehicles[count].model, token);
```

This last `strcpy` overflows the `vehicles` buffer. You probably meant to use a different index:

```
 strcpy(vehicles[count2].model, token);
```

It may also help to rename `count2` (which isn't a count at all) to something like `index`. You'll also want to increment that index somewhere within the loop.

In general, these kinds of bugs are trivial to find using proper tools. On Linux, you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [address sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by it overflowing the buffer on the vehicles?

Comment: @JeffreyHennen They way you allocated `vehicles`, valid indices for access to are in the half-open range `[0, count)`. The `vehicles[count]` is beyond the end of the allocated block.

Comment: Sorry, i meant to change that but it is going to be starting at 0 and ending at the end of file at n-1 for the index that i am going to be using

Comment: Okay, next question. How do i free this beast correctly?